# Where can I learn more about pthreads?

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am asked to work on a piece of code which relies heavily on pthreads. So many calls are made to this library that I know nothing of. I have learnt the basics of pthread and have tried out a few examples like creating joining etc. but dont know the depths of it.

I have learnt much of it using http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html

The above tutorial doesn't inlcude an indepth coverage of the pthread library that a beginner should need. Could u guys recommend a website or an eBook for me to have a look and learn most of the advanced stuff like signal handling, mutexes, concurrency etc.

TIA,
the_Saint

Answer (score 6):

https://hpc-tutorials.llnl.gov/posix/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads

[EDIT] First link was broken, now is fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Check out "Programming with POSIX threads" by Butenhof
(eg. [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633922))

Answer (score 2):

The best way to learn about any programing concepts is to go through the examples like to solve some problems using pthreads like Producer & consumer, Reader/writer problems and implement simple mathematics calculator etc.
there is some links which may help you,
http://www.humbug.org.au/talks/pthreads/examples.html,
http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~tyang/class/pthreads/index_sgi.html

There is also one book "Advanced Programming in the UNIX® Environment: Second Edition 
By W. Richard Stevens, Stephen A. Rago"

All the Best!

Answer (score 2):

As Ankit S states above, Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment is a good source.  Also, volume 2 of Unix Network Programming (also by Stevens) has a big section on posix semaphores and similar topics.

Answer (score 2):

http://randu.org/tutorials/threads/

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-posix1/index.html

http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node32.html

You can read a lot at stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pthreads+c